# Run a function on each element of a list in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory full of file pairs.  Each pair of files have the same name with the extensions of mp3 and cdg (karaoke files!).  I would like to use powershell to get the list of all distinct file names with no extensions

I've gotten as far as:

```
dir -recurse -filter "*.mp3" | select-object Name | sort
```

But I can't quite figure out how to pass each Name to  [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension

how would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the for-each (%) filter (not precisely sure if it's a filter or a cmdlet but it has the same usage syntax).

Try the following

```
dir -recurse -filter "*.mp3" | 
  %{ $_.Name } |
  %{ [IO::Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) } |
  sort
```

**EDIT** Update

I changed my answer from "`select-object Name`" to "`%{ $_.Name}`".  The former essentially takes the Name property off of the pipeline value and creates a new object with a single property of the specified name with the value on the original object.  The latter will process every value in the pipeline and pass the result of executing `$_.Name` down the pipeline.

Comment: That works but a) it gives me something like: @{Name=Mr Bungle - Backstrokin' - How do I get rid of the @{Name= part?  and b) what the heck did I just do?

Comment: @George, I updated my answer to get rid of the @Name part.  I'll add a response as to why that happens

Comment: foreach-object is a function.  You can verify this with gcm or simply by observing that % { "begin" } { "processing $_" } { "end" } works as expected.

Comment: ForEach-Object is a cmdlet here.

Comment: 'Function' and 'cmdlet' are more or less synonyms -- certainly so if you consider advanced functions in v2.  The important point is, % can't be a filter because filters don't have Begin & End blocks.

Answer (score 4):

dir -recurse -filter "*.mp3"| select @{name='Name';Expression={[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)}} | sort

Comment: +1.  Many people forget select's "hashtable syntax."  Too bad it's so ugly.  Would be much nicer to write select @{ Name = {some-expression}, Path = {some-otherexpression} }

Answer (score 2):

If you hate typing %{$_.foo} all the time like I do, try Get-PropertyValue (alias: gpv) from [PSCX](http://www.codeplex.com/Pscx).

More musings here for the suitably geeky: http://richardberg.net/blog/?p=55

Answer (score 2):

Now that PowerShell v2 is RTMd, you can select the BaseName member:

dir -recurse -filter *.mp3 | select BaseName | sort